# AWS .Net Core Sdk IAmzonS3.DeleteObjects fails silently

Tags: .net-core, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net, aws-s3-client

I'm using .NET 6 with .NET Sdk (v3) nuget package.
I need to delete a single (and only) file inside folder in S3 and the nested folders recursively. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I have tried to trace a pattern but none so far, seems to happen randomnly. However, in any case there is no way to learn the actual result from the application side.

I generate the necessary keys following the commented Example inside the function below, create and populate the `DeleteObjectsRequest` object and send the request. But theres no exception, no errors and the deleted objects collection within the response object has all the keys. However, it always successfully delete the file but some other times it fails to delete the remaning keys. In a few cases it happens to delete the next key after the file key but still fails to delete the others.

Believing it could be the order of processing at the bucket, I also tried creating a request per key in the reverse order starting from the file key, but the results are the same, every single request doesn't return or throw any error, the file key gets successfully deleted but the remaining keys don't.

`Deletion` is a record composed by a `DirectoryInfo` object and a `string` file path in the local server in the innermost folder.

```
private void RequestDelete(List<Deletion> DeleteItems, string SessionId)
        {
            /*
            Example keys distribution:
            SYNC_TEST/230502-1133-244190d8_df3ea364/AGT/2023/Month/30/PrefixedUploadFile.xlsx
            SYNC_TEST/230502-1133-244190d8_df3ea364/AGT/2023/Month/30/
            SYNC_TEST/230502-1133-244190d8_df3ea364/AGT/2023/Month/
            SYNC_TEST/230502-1133-244190d8_df3ea364/AGT/2023/
            SYNC_TEST/230502-1133-244190d8_df3ea364/AGT/
            SYNC_TEST/230502-1133-244190d8_df3ea364/
            */

            foreach (var item in DeleteItems)
            {
                try
                {
                    // add objects keys
                    var target = $"{prefix}{item.DirFile.Replace(sgwDir, "").Replace("\\", "/")}";
                    var remove = $"{Path.GetFileName(item.DirFile)}";
                    var dirObjects = new List<KeyVersion> { new() { Key = target }, new() { Key = target.Replace(remove, "") } };

                    foreach (var dir in item.DirPath.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Reverse())
                    {
                        remove = $"{dir.Name}/{remove}";
                        dirObjects.Add(new() { Key = target.Replace(remove, "") });
                    }

                    // print request keys
                    foreach (var obj in dirObjects) _logger.LogInformation($"[{SessionId}] [{obj.Key}] delete");

                    // send delete request to S3
                    var deleteRequest = new DeleteObjectsRequest { BucketName = bucket, Objects = dirObjects, Quiet = false };                    
                    var result = _s3client.DeleteObjectsAsync(deleteRequest).Result;

                    _logger.LogInformation($"[{SessionId}] [{item.DirPath}] request delete sent");

                    if (result.DeleteErrors.Count > 0 || result.DeletedObjects.Count < dirObjects.Count)
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation($"[{SessionId}] [{item.DirPath}] errors or no all objects deleted");

                        if (result.DeleteErrors.Count > 0)
                            foreach (var error in result.DeleteErrors) _logger.LogWarning($"[{SessionId}] [{error.Key}] {error.Message}");

                        if (result.DeletedObjects.Count < dirObjects.Count)
                            foreach (var deleted in result.DeletedObjects) _logger.LogWarning($"[{SessionId}] [{deleted.Key}] presumed deleted");
                    }                    
                }
                catch (Exception any)
                {
                    _logger.LogError($"[{SessionId}] {any.Message} Stack: {any.StackTrace}");
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.
J.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make your method async and use `await` instead of using .Response when calling the DeleteObjectsAsync method. The 2nd part of [this .NET example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/s3_example_s3_DeleteObjects_section.html) may be helpful - it shows how to use async/await with this request.

```
DeleteObjectsResponse response = await client.DeleteObjectsAsync(multiObjectDeleteRequest);
```